# Why JavaScript Engine Compile LET variable before initialization?

Tags: javascript, v8, jit

When we write code like bellow snippet JavaScript don't compile this code and return *Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'variableName' has already been declared* and we don't see "Hello World" in console

```js
function functionName() {
  console.log("Hello World");
}

functionName();
let variableName = "Murad";
let variableName = "Tofiq";
```

But when we write code like bellow snippet, code is compiled but return error in execution time and we see "Hello World" in console.

```js
function functionName() {
  console.log("Hello World");
}

functionName();
console.log(variableName);
let variableName = "Tofiq";
```

My question is JavaScript compiler know semantic analysis time we declare variable with let this is create TDZ(temproary dead zone) and this code return error. But why this code compile? Is this bug?

Comment: JavaScript compiles the entire script, it doesn't compile it sequentially.

Comment: @Barmar I understand not compile sequentially. But compiler can see "semantic alansysis" time this variable use before initilised and can stop compile return error. Like first code example

Comment: No this is only happened we declare variable with VAR. If you want to access variable declared with LET before initialization this is return error. Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'variableName' before initialization

Comment: Syntax errors are detected during parsing, reference errors are detected while running.

Comment: But why first example return error? This is also semantic error.

Comment: It's a syntax error to have two `let` declarations for the same variable.

Comment: I don't think. For example we can declare two variable same name with VAR. But this is not syntax error.

Comment: ```let``` is not hoisted, if you used ```var variableName``` ```console.log``` would be 'undefined'. When the js engine looks up scope it won't find ```variableName``` because its definition is not hoisted.

Comment: That's true. The new declarations in ES6 have different rules than the old `var` declaration.

Comment: @DanStarns Yeah bro I know let not hoisted. But problem on there engine also know let not hoisted and engine can say "Bro I can't compile this shitty code because let not hoisted this is not true semanticly" like my first code snippet.

Comment: The code will compile because all the complier is doing... allocating space in memory for your variables & creating an AST 'abstract syntax tree' for 'scope' but 'scope' is only looked up at runtime so hence why you get a runtime error.

Comment: Okay compiler create AST(Abstract Syntax Tree) that's true. This is happened Syntax Analysis time. But Compiler also have Semantic Analysis and in there AST convert to Annotated Abstract Syntax Tree and in there compiler can see semantic problems. Like my first code example in there code not compile because this is not true semanticly

Answer (score 1):

Your example is easy, but here is a slightly more interesting one:

```
function f() { return g }
let h = f()
if (b) h()
let a = 7
function g() { return a }
```

In general, it is highly non-trivial (even undecidable) to detect in advance whether a variable is used before initialisation. So it was deemed too complicated and ultimately futile to try, and it would be inconsistent if it was only rejected in some cases.

In contrast, detecting duplicate bindings is always trivial.

Comment: Okay it makes a little more sense. But I think we forget one thing. For example in your snippet that's true we don't need detect variable is used before initialisation. But JavaScript can see this variable declared with LET and in one scope you can't use variable before LET declaration. And I think this not problem check only TDZ(Temproary Dead Zone) in compile time.

Comment: And also I forget say V8 also check all variable is variable declared in current scope or not and if variable not declared in scope engine search variable parent scope if found it add in Closure object. This process happened on compile time. If you don't believe me I can show this via chrome developer tool

Comment: As I said, the JS committee didn't want to introduce incoherent rules -- either something is always checked statically or never. Disclosure: I was on that committee. And I implemented `let` in V8, so I know what it does. ;)

Comment: OMG So cool :)  But everywhere have static rules :d I think you must think about this. When we declare variable same name with let and Ecma International also say we can't do it I think this problem can solve on compiler time :)

Comment: And my last question Why you don't implement for performance issue or another reason?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. V8 implements what the standard prescribes. There is no other choice.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because JavaScript runs in a [host environment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/About_JavaScript#What_JavaScript_implementations_are_available).

The V8 JavaScript compiler/interpreter, strictly-speaking, cannot know at *parsetime* that `variableName` does not already exist in the global environment. So while declaring a `const` or `let` twice within the same function scope (or environment) is a `SyntaxError`, the 2nd example you gave is a *runtime* `ReferenceError`, because it is not generated until the code is executed.

TypeScript can detect these things however, because it has knowledge of the environment in which it runs (via configuration), so it will correctly complain and refuse to compile references to global variables it doesn't know about.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But actually I don't understand your first sentence. What is relationship between first code exmaple and global environment.

Comment: @andreas-rossberg can probably answer more correctly than I, but you can think of every closure or function you write as it's own "environment". Variables declared inside of that environment "close over" variables or bindings in higher environments. So when you write some javascript in a <script> tag, that JS is executing in the global environment as defined by the ^ host.

Comment: So when you give the parser some random bit of JS as Andreas mentioned, it can easily detect a repeated variable declaration, but it does not have the knowledge to detect references to undefined variables, because the global environment can vary wildly.

Comment: The above is a browser example. But node.js is very similar, instead when you write some code to a file and run `node code.js`. That code is executed inside of an environment that looks like this: https://blog.risingstack.com/node-js-at-scale-module-system-commonjs-require/#whatisthemodulesystem (third code snippet) One could reasonably make the argument that NodeJS *could* enable an option that would throw a syntax error if you reference undefined vars in the context of a module, but as mentioned it is harder than it sounds and could lead to unpredictable behavior.

Comment: Yeah I answer also @andreas-rossberg. Global environment can vary wildly but problem in there JavaScript can know variable declared with LET in scope and when we decalare variable with let this is create TDZ(Temproary Dead Zone) and compiler can see this is declaration create TDZ in this scope and variable can't use before initilasing. And we don't need worry about Global Scope

Comment: Problem in there we don't need wory what happened Global Scope or variable declared with eval. In there problem AST(Abstract Syntax Tree) analysis time compiler can saw variable declared with LET and before using not acceptible. I think  V8 team can fix this very easy way

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197973/discussion-between-jon-jaques-and-murad-sofiyev).